# excel drop-down list according to your select

Tags: excel, list

I need 4 drop-down list according to select without repetition in the drop-down list.

Sheets Main: Select Car, Select type, Select Vendor, Select Fuel from range sheet "DB"

Url to download example file:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5yzT9H5JZGKWjFzY3RqRXJTMGs
```

First example

```
If i'm select list car i have value Fiat and Mercedes Benz
If i'm select list type i have value Sedan and Combi
If i'm select list vendor i have value AVIS and PANEK
If i'm select list Fuel i have value Diesel and Benzin
```

Secound example

```
If i'm select list car i have value Fiat and Mercedes Benz and Volvo
If i'm select list type i have value Sedan and Van
If i'm select list vendor i have value AVIS
If i'm select list Fuel i have value Diesel
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://www.excelkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5942) might help - unless it is more advanced than you need.
This is a [simpler version](http://www.excelkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2330) designed for simpler requirements.